# LinkedIn does not show images from shared Joomla articles

Tags: joomla, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

This is a quite strange issue. I have a Joomla 3.4.5 site and when I share an article in LinkedIn, image and article description are not included. This doesn't happen with other links where blog layout e.g. is used. Only articles. It seems they are excluded for some reason. It is not a server issue, my other sites have no such problem. Even installed an Open Graph plugin. Any ideas? Thank you. Example link: http://opk.gr/news/26-achema-2015

Answer (score 0):

By default your articles won't have the Facebook or Twitter meta tags.

This article will explain the best method for adding them in correctly.

https://www.dart-creations.com/joomla/joomla-tutorials/add-facebook-open-graph-and-twitter-cards-to-joomla.html